# Enable SQL logging with Batoo JPA

Tags: sql, jpa, batoo

How do you enable SQL logging with Batoo JPA

Answer (score 2):

You can enable it by

```
log4j.logger.org.batoo.jpa.core.SQL=DEBUG
```

in your log4j.properties file

or without dealing with the logger and pass a property into persistance.xml to redirect the sql log to STD_OUT or STD_ERR
as in example;

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd" version="2.0">

<persistence-unit name="default">
    <provider>org.batoo.jpa.core.BatooPersistenceProvider</provider>

    <class>org.batoo.jpa.core.test.simple.Foo</class>

    <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
        <property name="org.batoo.jpa.ddl" value="DROP" />
        <!--org.batoo.jpa.sql_logging :: NONE | STDOUT | STDERR -->
        <property name="org.batoo.jpa.sql_logging" value="STDERR" />
    </properties>

</persistence-unit>
```

But enabling log4j to DEBUG level will log the  query parameters values as a bonus which is better then question marks.